# How to correctly understand PROCESS model 4 for output “ Test of X by M interaction?

Tags: interaction, spss, mediation

Perhaps some one can help me interpret some of the outputs of Hayes model 4. I designed a questionnaire that had good Cronbach and KMO scores etc. I did the PCA and have four components (factors). I have now done some mediation analysis with PROCESS model 4 and need some clarification regarding the following:

- If the “Test of X by M interaction” is sig. p<0.05 what exactly is this telling me and what should be the next analysis?
- If this test is not significant, what does that imply for the relationships between the variables?
- Is it important if the “direct effect of X on Y” is not significant? And why would it meant if the “test of X by M..” is significant but the Direct X on Y is not?

Comment: I don't know about Hayes models, but your question seems to be quite general about variables, interactions, and significance. Can you put it in more general terms?

Answer (score 0):

I am conducting mediation analysis with 3 variables. X,Y,and M. There are many different possible outcomes and I am having difficulty drawing conclusions. I understand how to determine whether a variables is mediating etc..i just don’t know what exactly Hayes process model 4 test of X by M interaction is saying. The relationships between all variables is significant, direct effect of X on Y is significant but the test of X by M interaction is not and apparently in this case I cannot use the data. I cannot find any explanation regarding this test anywhere?